# Не правильно работает парсер php

Tags: php, html

В общем простой, незамысловатый парсер, который работает только в верхней части страницы. Гугл сказал, что надо использовать $start и $finish, но если я их прописываю вообще ничего не парсится. Сайт-донор имеет такую структуру:

```
<div class="firm-list-item firm-place-1">~контент который нужно забрать~</div>
<div class="firm-list-item firm-place-2">~контент который нужно забрать~</div>
<div class="firm-list-item firm-place-2">~контент который нужно забрать~</div>
```

Вот между 1 и 2 дивами контент забирается, а дальше нет..
Вот код самого парсера:

```
$title=file_get_contents($url);
$start = '<div class="firm-list-item firm-place-2">';
$finish = '<div class="firm-list-item firm-place-3">';
$pos=strpos($title,'<a class="firm-item-title" href=');
$title=substr($title,$pos);
$pos1=strpos($title,'</a>');
$title=substr($title,0,$pos1);
$title=preg_replace('<a class="firm-item-title" href="/firm/id/[0-9]+/">','',$title);
echo $title;
echo '<br>';
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем тут проблема(где написать $start и $finish?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь библиотекой PHPQuery (https://github.com/punkave/phpQuery)
проще будет.

```
require ('phpQuery/phpQuery.php');


function get_content_by_url($url_target) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_target); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Google Bot'); 
    $data = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}

$url_target = 'http://example.site.com/';

$html_content = get_content_by_url($url_target);
$document = phpQuery::newDocument($html_content);

$found_items = $document->find('div.firm-list-item[class^="firm-place-"]');

$print = '';

foreach($found_items as $key => $item) {
    $pq = pq($item);

    $content_text = pq($item)->text(); // только текст
    $content_html = pq($item)->html(); // весь html (контент)

    $print .= '<li class="my_item">'. $content_html .'</li>';
}

$final_contentt = '<ul class="my_list">'. $print . '</ul>';

echo $final_contentt;
```

по идее должно работать.

Comment: ответ норм но в кратце опишите как

Comment: ну и на будущее `get_content_by_url` заменимо на `file_get_contents($url)`

Comment: уж лучше через curl, чем file_get_contents

Comment: чем лучше?                 .......

Comment: А  чем он хуже ?

Comment: вы сказали "уж лучше через curl, чем file_get_contents" ну так аргументируйте чем лучше?

Comment: выже умный такой, почему бы вам не ответить ?

Comment: Правила этикета не  слышали? я вас спросил чем лучше? а вы вопросом на вопрос отвечаете, аргументируйте(докажите почему) свои умозаключения

Comment: ну так а в чем проблема вам ответить? Вы же знаете, разве нет?

Comment: Понял тяжёлый случай.... Потому что `get_content_by_url` реализует функционал `file_get_contents` так что не зачем писть 10 строк кода, когда уже есть реализация такой функции...

Comment: слушайте, ваш тяжелый случай в том, что вы влезли в чужой вопрос и сыпете свои вставки без своих аргументов между прочим, так что за своим этикетом последите пожалуйста и за своими случаями.

Comment: с этого и стоило начинать ... про 10 строк кода. а не обновлять сообщения после моего ответа

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52197/discussion-between-naumov-and-dr-mc-my).

Comment: curl как минимум быстрее.

Comment: с чего такие выводы?

Comment: разбирался, пробовал, знаю

Comment: Не правда, как минимум в php вызов пользовательской функции более трудоёмкая операция по сравнению с вызовом проприетарной функции.

Comment: Если вы так хотите, можете оставаться с таким мнением, я буду не против. А засорять комментами своими не стоит.

Comment: СО не для того что бы мерятся ответами )) и не выяснять кто прав а кто виноват.